# Color of the text not changing when hovering over a button

Tags: html, css, button

I am new to CSS, and I am trying to implement a button, which will have its text and background colors changed when hovering over it. While the change of the background color is working, it is not the case for the text. Could you please let me know what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

HTML

```css
button {
  background: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1.5px solid #4ca37f;
  color: #4ca37f;
  padding: 1px 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: #1595eb;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

```html
<div class="button">
  <button type="button">Follow</button>
</div>
```

Comment: You are changing the text color for the _div_, not the button. So if the button already has a color specified, it won't inherit it from the div now. `.button:hover` should be `button:hover`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apply style to button tag `button:hover` instead of `.button:hover`

```css
button {
  background: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1.5px solid #4ca37f;
  color: #4ca37f;
  padding: 1px 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #1595eb;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

```html
<div class="button">
  <button type="button">Follow</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second CSS rule, `.button:hover` essentially targets the **.button** class. If I'm understanding you correctly, you would like the `background-color` and `color` of the actual button to be changed when you hover over the div. This means you have to target the `button` inside `.button`, such as:

```
.button:hover button {
  background-color: #1595eb;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```